# How do I fix this error: "attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm making an SKAction sequence and I put two other SKActions inside of the sequence and it gives me this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray
initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
```

objects[1]"

When I put an exception break point, it pointed to this line:

> SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, moveDown]];

Here is the entire method code:

```
-(void) animateLetters{

    moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:15 duration:2];
    moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-15 duration:2];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, moveDown]];

    SKAction *runForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
    [letter1 runAction:runForever];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `moveUp` twice and `moveDown` never.  In this case it would probably make more sense to use local variables -

```
-(void) animateLetters{

    SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:15 duration:2];
    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-15 duration:2];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, moveDown]];

    SKAction *runForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
    [letter1 runAction:runForever];
}
```